# Updating drivers in Windows 10/Ubuntu 14.04 dualboot

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, windows, dual-boot

I have just recently installed Ubuntu onto my Win10 Laptop on a HP Probook 4530S. Both seem to be working fine with GRUB as the bootloader.

I was trying to install an upgrade to the Intel Chipset on my laptop, but it seems to fail despite showing as a success. Am I locked into the current chipset on the Windows side? Or do I need to install my drivers on the Ubuntu side? I am really enjoying my Linux experience, and I want to see if I can make this work. I'll need Windows programs here and there, so I want to keep my Windows 10 install.

5/16

I am trying to update the intel chipset driver on Windows 10, but it never seems to install.

Comment: Can you be more specific as what you have done 'install an upgrade' ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to upgrade. Is this a driver for the operating system or a firmware update for your hardware?

Answer (score 0):

Each OS is independent of each other so any issues with installing Windows drivers are unrelated to having Ubuntu installed. Drivers are OS specific as well, so installing one in Ubuntu will have no effect on Windows.

Comment: True of drivers, but not of firmware nor hardware.  I don't know that your answer applies to an upgrade to the chipset.

Comment: I agree. The question is not very clear on what exactly the user is attempting. Most people only ever upgrade drivers and not firmware so I assumed that's what it was about.